# Language-ext: chain Either<L, R> with Option?

Tags: language-ext

I am just starting with language-ext, trying to use it in my Azure Function.

In this function, I first parse/validate the POSTed data from the HTTP request using some validator.
This validator returns an Either<ValidationErrors, RequestModel>.
Then I would like to chain onto the either result a service call that should use the request model to grab some data from an API an return an Option.
At the end of the chain I would then like to return an IActionResult BadRequest if there were ValidationErrors in the first step, or otherwise perform a Match on the result of the service call Option to either return a NotFoundResult or ObjectResult.

The issue I run into is that if I want to chain my service call (using Bind, or BiBind) after the Either<ValidationErrors, GetRequestModel>, then the signature of my service method must be some Either<ValidationErrors, ...>, which is incorrect, since my service method has nothing to do with ValidationErrors. It should just return an Option.

So I guess my question is how can  preserve any ValidationErrors until the end of the chain, and be able to chain my service call with a Option signature onto an Either?

Answer (score 0):

You have to decide what the result of your chained expression is.

Option:

```
var maybeResult = from validated in GetValidationResult(...).ToOption()
                  from apiResult in ApiCall(...)
                  select apiResult;
```

Either:

```
var resultOrError = from validated in GetValidationResult(...)
                    from apiResult in ApiCall(...).ToEither(*LEFT*)
                    select apiResult;
```

You have to replace `*LEFT*` by some error value or error generating function returning same type like `left` type of `GetValidationResult`.

Replace above pseudo code with your own code and look at the return types of the functions used above to see what's going on.

The reason why you need a common `left` type is that the bind operation can return some `left` (error) of first (GetValidationResult) or second (ApiCall) function call -- or `right` of your last (ApiCall) function if your reach successful end of your chain.

Recommendation: If you mix different `left` (error) return types you might want to use some thing like LanguageExt's built-in `Error` type or maybe just a plain string (or `Exception`).

Either with `string` as error type:

```
var resultOrError = from validated in GetValidationResult(...).MapLeft(Prelude.toString)
                    from apiResult in ApiCall(...).ToEither("api call failed")
                    select apiResult;
```

Additional note: I use LINQ style here, you can use method style:

```
var resultOrError = GetValidationResult(...)
                    .MapLeft(Prelude.toString)
                    .Bind(validated => ApiCall(...)
                                       .ToEither("api call failed"));
```

Comment: Thanks @stb for the answer. Based on your response it was clear how to proceed. In the end I used something like the following code to perform request model creation, validation, call my service, and generate a response. I am using an Either<Errors, XXX> in my flow. Within the Errors, I remember if it was validation errors or not. Then in the end when I match the result to a IActionResult, I convert the Errors to an IActionResult using the validation property. When the errors are validation errors I create a BadRequest result, otherwise I create a InternalServerError result.